# How does codeigniter threats libraries loaded more than once?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Could someone explain me how does Codeigniters handle the load of a library previously loaded?

1. Are the library loaded once again?
2. Does it simply jumps into the next function call?

This is something that might happen accidentally. Recently, while working on a project, I created an hook for post_controller_constructor and inside of it i start loading a class to enhance the functionality of my website.

With the hook on place i forgot to remove the old load library call from my controllers.

Curiously, nothing of wrong happened.
I was expecting an exception telling me that the library was already loaded or something like that.

Comment: CI keeps track of what's loaded and what's not, so there's no loading twice the same resource (libraries,models,helpers, all those works the same way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CI checks if library is not set.

As you can see in this code :

```
public function library($library = '', $params = NULL, $object_name = NULL)
{
    if (is_array($library))
    {
        foreach ($library as $class)
        {
            $this->library($class, $params);
        }

        return;
    }

    if ($library == '' OR isset($this->_base_classes[$library]))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ( ! is_null($params) && ! is_array($params))
    {
        $params = NULL;
    }

    $this->_ci_load_class($library, $params, $object_name);
}
```

`system\code\Loader.php`